# What is the colloquial way to say one will log into one of those famous streaming video services to choose any TV show to watch?

Tags: colloquial-language

I am not sure whether "put on" is the right one as I am getting anything inside a DVD player or any other device. Nor I do believe the verb play is suitable in this particular case.

Here are two examples.

Hey dad! Let's play Monk on Netflyx

Hey meemaw! Let's put on Monk on Amason Brime.

And what if it was something I have to do before doing something else?

Here is the example: I have to put on/play Monk on my mother's television for her to watch it before I go to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Let's *watch* film X on platform Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Put on" seems reasonable, as the phrase "Put on the news" would be acceptable even if it was a 24/7 channel.

> Here is the example: I have to put on/play Monk on my mother's television for her to watch it before I go to work.

"Start an episode of.."?

Comment: Thank you very much! In Spanish we always use"poner". It is very rare to use another verb rather than the one I am telling you. It is  a very general way to say you will start/put on/play an episode of a TV show on any apparatus screen.